# Switching between Windows 10 OS and Ubuntu16.04 (Linux 0S) without disrupting service of any OS

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Currently all the AIV`s we have operate of Linux operating system (OS) & Ubuntu, so I have an external boot drive to operate Linux OS and I have my Windows 10 Laptop to carry out other work.

So at the moment, to operate one OS, I must shutdown the other OS.

My question is, is it possible to have a dual boot system and have both operating systems running simultaneously, and if I switch from one to another is it possible to do so without distributing any service?

My guess is NO and that I will need to use a VM, but any input/advice on this would be greatly appreciated

Note: I would like to stay away from using a VM if possible as it caused me serious issues for a number of weeks which lead me to go and use an external boot drive for Linux.

Thank you.

Comment: You are correct. Only a VM will meet the needs you describe.

Comment: If you are running W10 64-bit, then enable WSL and then go to the store and get Ubuntu.  You can then run both Windows and Linux without any VMs.  The only problem is that Ubuntu is either 18.04 or 20.04.  There isn't a 16.04.  Need to check whether your AIVs can run on WSL.